# How to Generalize functions in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm writing some Code that does some basic analysis on data.

The data collected is in an array of structs. It takes the approximate form:

```
struct page {
  int width;
  int length;
  char name[50];
  // etc...
}

struct page pages[100];
```

I need to write code that finds the smallest width, largest width, smallest length, largest length, etc. So I write code that looks something like this:

```
int smallestWidth(struct page pages[]){
unsigned int smallest = -1;
  (for loop){
    if (smallest > pages[i].width) smallest = pages[i].width;
  }
return smallest;
}
```

And then I find that I'm copy-pasting this function and changing tiny details for the other requirements like largest width. And whenever I'm copy-pasting chunks of code, that raises alarm bells for me, and I'm thinking I'm doing it wrong.

But, I'm kind of new to C, so I'm not sure what the right way to approach this is.
How would you write this in C properly (if there is a proper way) that minimizes the amount of code that I'm copy-pasting?

Comment: You could use a macro function to reduce the duplication a bit but not totally. But you would also lose some maintainability

Comment: Do you have to iterate the array multiple times (once for each metric) ? Why not iterate once, and calculate all metrics in one go ?

Comment: You can think about this problem if structure members are 10-20 or more. For 4-5 similar copy-paste functions it is not worth it to complicate the algorithm. Otherwise you can define `width`, `length`, etc. members of the same type as elements of array and then scan it with a loop (`smallest` values will be in another array).

Comment: The sound way would be to have the data sorted after the "primary key", whatever that is in this case. You'd then be able to at least implement binary search for that one. Overall, writing generic code with function pointers etc is quite possible, but you should probably start to consider how you store the data first. Rolling out a whole lot of naive for loops isn't a good solution performance-wise.

Comment: My main concern in this case was readability, not necessarily performance. I know that when I read code the impression I get from copy-paste is not great. But I do like the performance suggestions, I'll keep them in mind for if I need to write faster code.

Answer (score 1):

C++ language has overrides and pointer to members that C has not. So the C way would be to use auxilliary functions to extract the correct data and compare them:

```
int getLength(struct page *page) {
    return page->length;
}
int getWidth(struct page *page) {
    return page->width;
}

int lesser(int a, int b) {
    return a<b;
}
int greater(int a, int b) {
    return a>b;
}

typedef int(*extractor)(struct page *p);
typedef int (*comparator)(int a, int b);

int process(struct page * p, int size, extractor ext, comparator cmp) {
    // code here the generic part
    ...
}

int lesserWidth = process(pages, 100, &getWidth, &lesser);
...
```

But it includes a good deal of boiler plate code, so it may be interesting or not depending on the complexity of the generic part...

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Some people like to give emphasis that it is a function pointer. It's really just a matter of style and I don't think there's any right or wrong here. Related, I personally prefer `typedef int extractor (struct page *p);` ... `extractor* ext` since that makes the function pointer syntax consistent with object pointer syntax.

Comment: Yes, the pointer discussion. I prefer the `int *p` notation to make clear the pointer should never be included in a `typedef`. But it is all a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be classified as a Horrible Hack, however, it satisfies your request. It only works for integers because of the compare.

```
struct page {
  int width;
  int length;
  // etc...
} pages[100] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

int smallestX(struct page pages[], size_t offset)
{
    unsigned int smallest = -1, k;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        k= *((int *)((char *)(&pages[i])+offset));
        if (smallest > k) smallest = k;
  }
  return smallest;
}
void example(void)
{
    printf ("smallest width= %d\n", smallestX(pages, offsetof(struct page, width)));
    printf ("smallest length= %d\n", smallestX(pages, offsetof(struct page, length)));
}
```

Clarification:

It uses the `offsetof` macro to get the offset of the member from the beginning of the struct. In the function, it now takes the address of the `i`th element of the array, interprets that as a byte address, adds the offset (which is in bytes), interprets that as a pointer to an int, dereferences that int and uses it in the compare.

Note: it is possible to extend this method to compare any item by providing a compare function as parameter.